# 'Painted' or 'painting' after 'want' + NP

Tags: differences, past-participles, present-participles

Which is correct? Is it, "Do you want your house painting" or "Do you want your house painted"? Examples of both can be found on the internet.

Is there a difference between them? Can you use either?

Comment: Related, and maybe providing the answer: [How are "needs to be washed," "needs washing," and the regional variant "needs washed" to be distinguished"?](/q/24163)

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's a different issue, and doesn't have an answer for this question.

Comment: These are complex catenation patterns. CGEL gives 'I saw them fighting' as an example using the -ing form after the NP; 'I had my car stolen / washed' (different senses!) show  examples of the [NP + past participle] type. Here, 'Do you want your house painting?' sounds natural, while 'Do you want your house painted?' sounds slightly dialectal IMO (hence Andrew's suggestion of a duplicate). But nowhere near  as dialectal as 'this house needs painted'. ////  cf 'I want this finishing/finished by tomorrow'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You really think that "Do you want your house painting?" sounds natural? The exact opposite is true for me. Do you think "the house was painting" is natural? And, given the fact that we're even having this conversation at all, should the question really be closed? This is not related to the other question, since a quick search for "want this work finished/finishing" shows that the version with "finished" is overwhelming preferred.

Comment: There are  hits in a Google search for "want your house painting" as well as in one for "want your house painted". I've forgotten (if I knew), Laurel ... are you from the States? This could be quite heavily influenced by locality. I feel that the catenation after 'want' (and 'need') [+ NP] using the -ed form is more American in flavour.

Comment: @Laurel "Do you want the house painting" is perfectly cromulent in BrE.

Comment: I've found this [[Basil Cottle; Survey of English Dialects](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Survey+of+English+Dialects%3A+The+Dictionary+and+Grammar-a018667391)]: " 'I want this finishing by Friday', here assigned only to Yorkshire, is certainly a Geordie trait, too." I'm from Oldham (in Lancashire as was), and it's totally natural to my ears.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I speak an American dialect (specifically one that *doesn't* include "needs washed", though I'm familiar with the construction).

Comment: Perhaps the idiomaticity is dependent on the actual V, NP and V-participle.  'The car needs/needed its oil changing' sounds quite a lot more natural to my ears than 'The car needs/needed its oil changed', while 'I'd like my fence painting/painted white' sound equally natural.

Comment: For you Brits who hear nothing wrong with "Do you want your house painting", is **house** there a modifier, like **duct** in "duct cleaning"?

Comment: We have a saying in the UK "If you want something doing, do it yourself"

Comment: @TimR No, it isn't.

Comment: @TimR - No. I would interpret _Do you want your house painting?_ as implying 'Do you want someone to paint it?', while the other version is _Do you want your house [to be] painted?_

Comment: I am familiar with 18th c locutions like "the ship is repairing" which in AmE would be paraphrased as "the ship is being repaired", because for us **repair** is transitive. Do you Brits say "the house is painting"?

Comment: The AmE counterpart is "If you want something done, do it yourself."

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. CGEL always confuses me when it uses example sentences that work in BrE but not AmE. I've left a bunch of comments on Edwin Ashworth's answer but I can't find a good source on this difference.

Comment: I would rephrase it as "Does your house need painting?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I cannot find via Google nor duckduckgo a page where "want the house painting" means "have a desire for the house to receive a new coat of paint."  The closest I see is references to a project of painting a house, such as "I want the house painting finished before winter."

Comment: @phoog Try here: [Do you want the house painting yellow?](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=D-ky9mRK-0oC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22want+the+house+%C2%A0painting%22&source=bl&ots=eLamO35Dl7&sig=ACfU3U1pc-fmQOpKhUthuF5HWzxZrr-dCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVi6fZvOuAAxVdQUEAHQCzBrwQ6AF6BAgvEAM#v=onepage&q=%22want%20the%20house%20%C2%A0painting%22&f=false)

Comment: Both are correct, which is partly why the Question belongs not here, but in SE English Language Learners…

Answer (score -1):

These are complex catenation patterns. CGEL gives

> - *I saw them fighting*

as an example using the -ing form after the NP;

> - *I had my car stolen / washed*                         (different senses of *have NP V-ed*!)

show examples of the [NP + past participle] type.

So both constructions are considered acceptable by CGEL, but that doesn't mean that they're always equally idiomatic (some might even say grammatical) for all V + NP + V-ing/V-ed complex catenations.

In discussion with others in comments, it becomes clear that idiomaticity is dependent not only on the actual verbs / direct objects involved, but also on region.

Coming from the NW of England, I find

- *The car needs/needed its oil changing*                   to be more natural-sounding than
- *The car needs/needed its oil changed*.

But I find

- *I'd like my fence painting white*                               and
- *I'd like my fence painted white*                                 equally natural.

While the -ing form connotes doing, activity, and the -ed form the completed state, it's fair to say the variants are closely synonymous. 'I'd like my fence to be painted white' say (though 'I like my fence painted white' may be either a deleted form of 'I like my fence to be painted white' [iterative] or an object-oriented depictive construction meaning 'I like my fence in this white paint'. Compare 'I like my oysters rare'.

(Obviously the ambiguity as with "Do you really want your son painting?" doesn't arise in this case, but external context will almost always disambiguate.)

And while [Basil Cottle, in *Survey of English Dialects*](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Survey+of+English+Dialects%3A+The+Dictionary+and+Grammar-a018667391), writes " 'I want this finishing by Friday', here assigned only to Yorkshire, is certainly a Geordie trait, too", Araucaria (' "Do you want the house painting" is perfectly cromulent in BrE' and 'We have a saying in the UK "If you want something doing, do it yourself" ') states that this is far more general.

On the other hand, Laurel, writing in the United States, says that to her ears,

- *Do you want your house painting?*"                        sounds **less** natural than
- *Do you want your house painted?*

I'd say that this is largely, though confusingly not totally, a regional difference, with the past participle preferred consistently in the States, but the present participle often preferred (though not to the exclusion of the past participle) in the UK.

Comment: This is something that perplexed me reading CGEL recently. To me, "The car needs its oil changing" sounds not just wrong but completely nonsensical. Usually, when my intuitions differ from H&P that much, it's because the construction is valid in BrE but not AmE. But I wasn't able to find any source saying that this is a difference between dialects.

Comment: "My house needs painting" sounds fine to me. But "I need my house painting" sounds totally wrong. ("My house wants painting" and "I want my house painting" also sound wrong, but I know that that is a BrE/AmE difference.)

Comment: "I want/need my house painted" are both fine, albeit a bit unusual. But "My house needs/wants painted" also sound like nonsense to me.

Comment: (H&P have a habit of overlooking AmE/BrE differences, or mentioning them only at the end of a chapter/section. This often leaves me deeply confused, since I spend quite a while wondering why they're using example sentences that sound *obviously wrong.*)

Comment: (I suppose "I want my house painting" would make sense if the *house* was doing the painting; "I want my employees working hard" sounds alright.)

Comment: @alphabet: I speak mid-atlanticAmE and don't find anything amiss with "That door wants fixing" or "That shirt needs mending" or "That house needs painting" but like you I wouldn't say "I want my house painting" or "I want my shirt mending" but "painted" and "mended" instead.

Comment: Edwin, do Brits say "My house is painting" that is to say, "getting painted" or "being painted"? Referring to the ongoing activity?

Comment: No. Like you, I would consider it archaic.

Comment: No, Tim, the ergative isn't available with _paint_. Contrast 'His old house scrubbed up well', 'this painting cleaned nicely', 'the paint dried quickly'; I'm still working on how to analyse 'she takes a good photograph' (= is photogenic).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For you, is "I want my employees cleaning" ambiguous between "I want my employees to clean" and "I want my employees to *be* cleaned"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: She cleans up real nice.

Comment: "Cromulent"? I take it you're a Simpsons fan.

Comment: @alphabet If it were not for the fact that 'clean' rarely takes an animate DO, it would be. I'm trying to think of a more suitable example. Perhaps 'I need this chicken eating as soon as possible.'